# Flume agent does not stop retrying for unrecoverable solr error

Tags: solr, flume, avro, flume-ng

I am using Morphline Solr Sink to store information in Solr. The problem that I am facing is that flume agent never stops retrying the failed requests, which sometimes can increase over time. This results in the flume warning of MaxIO Workers being used and the system suffers with performance issues. Is there any way other than writing my own sink, that can make flume stop retrying or backoff exponentially to have a better system performance? My source is an avroSource.

Thanks.

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking, could you clarify it and edit your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix the reason for the failed requests.

Flume is doing exactly what it's designed to do. It's transactionally trying to store the batch of events in your store. If it can't store those events then, yes, it keeps on trying.

You haven't explained what the problem is causing these failures. I would recommend thinking about an interceptor to fix whatever is wrong in the data or to drop events you don't want to store.

Comment: The data was being stored in Solr, but due to an error in fieldtype, it cannot be stored in solr, no matter how many times it is retried. I was looking at interceptors, but can they be used to drop events like these?

Comment: You have two choices. Either fix the configuration so there's no longer an error; or drain the queue using the FileRoleSink or the NullSink. You can use a custom interceptor to re-write the event into something valid.

Comment: Ohh. I see. I will try with a custom interceptor to see if i can drain the queue. Thanks for the advice.